# Manually change form in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, triggers

I am trying to trigger the `change()` function of my form manually with jQuery 1.7.2, but it doesn't work. This is my code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

     console.log('going to change form');

     $('form[name="newBom"] input').trigger('change');

     $('form[name="newBom"] input').change(function() {
            console.log('form changed');
     });
 });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not getting the expected functionality as you are triggering the `change` even before a `change` handler is bound to your input(s). You can correct this by triggering the `change` event *after* binding the `change` handler:

```
// bind the handler
$('form[name="newBom"] input').change(function() {
    console.log('form changed');
});

// now, trigger the change event
$('form[name="newBom"] input').trigger('change');
```

Comment: @undefined - Yes, you're right. Fixed one of them in my answer above. The second needs to be fixed too for the script to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

     console.log('going to change form');

     //Attach event handler first
     $('form[name="newBom"] input').change(function() {
            console.log('form changed');
     }); // missing );

     //Trigger event
     $('form[name="newBom"] input').trigger('change');


 }); //missing );
```

** Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/RG5gn/

Comment: Just a note, `);` is missing after the change binding statement as well.

Comment: @techfoobar Thanks I missed that one.